# Audigy LS sound card plays static or white noise on Dell 9100 with ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am upgrading and old Dell 9100 that came with a Dell (OEM) Audigy LS sound card and Windows XP.  Everything is working OK except the sound.

When you try to play a sound, all you get is static or white noise.  When the playing stops, the static goes away.  I used the test buttons in the sound settings as well as playing sound from the browser.

I have played with alsamixer to get 63 <> 63.

I completely re-installed Ubuntu also.

I played around with pulseaudio also.

I selected analog input on the input tab of the sound settings.

The sound card shows up as SB0310 Audigy LS.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With alsamixer, locate and mute SPDIF/IEC958 channel (<kbd>m</kbd> to mute when fader is selected with arrows key)
(from [there](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man4/snd_emu10kx.4freebsd.html))